# My Amazon lex does not send a proper event to my lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, amazon-lex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGRcq.png)When setting up my Amazon lex to build a bot, I wrote a lambda function so that I can integrate it with my code. I kept on getting a 'sessionstate' keyerror, I even tried creating a new bot and starting over but it did not change
When I checked the log from lex this is what I got

{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}

It does not have the sessionState or currentIntent, nothing just the values above

[ERROR] KeyError: 'sessionstate'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 5, in lambda_handler

slots= event ['sessionstate']['intent']['slots']

Above is the log of the error

I've  been stock here for days now.please how can I solve this problem?

I tried creating a new bot and new lambda function but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `'key1': 'value1'` stuff is coming from the Test Event in your Lambda function. I presume you are running your code by pressing the Test button.

[image: Lambda test event]

If you wish to test your code against a typical Lex response, then you can change the Test values to match what your code is expecting. Alternatively, call your function through Lex and it will pass the appropriate values to your code.

See also: [Interpreting the input event format - Amazon Lex](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda-input-format.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the event passed to my lambda function does not seem to have the correct format and that's why the sessionState is not recognised and I cannot write any lambda code to retrieve the information from lex that is where my issue is

Comment: It's often useful to star the Lambda function with `print(event)` to see what it contains. The event will appear in the CloudWatch Logs file.

Comment: The cloudWatch log file does not have the format that you specified above, it rather has the 'key' :'value1' instead of sessionState and the other values

Comment: How are you triggering the Lambda function? Hint: You should not be using the Test button unless you have provided a custom Test Event.

Comment: Yes. I actually tested it using Amazon lex(through the intent) then I checked the log file through the lambda function but it never once showed the way it was supposed to